# choose up to x number of items from a list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have a list of items where I want the user to be able to select up to three items.
I have the below code.

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var clickcnt = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
    listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if(this.hasAttribute('class')){
        var test = document.getElementsByClassName('clicked');
        this.classList.remove('clicked');
        clickcnt--;
      }
      else if(clickcnt < 3) {
      this.classList.add('clicked');
      clickcnt++;
      }
console.log(clickcnt);
    });
}
```

```css
    .clicked {
      background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<p>select up to 3 of your favourite items below.</p>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

The issue I am having is that I am checking to see if the item has a class if so I am reducing the click count.  But it keeps subtracting the items so if I for example click on item 1 4 times in a row I am then able to select the other four.

How can I set this up so the user can keep clicking on an item until they have a max of 3 selected but if they click on the same one twice it removes the item so that it is at its intial state?

Comment: Can you use jquery? It would be much simpler

Comment: On line 6 you declare the variable `test` and then never use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var toggleClicked = function(event) {
  var _class = 'clicked';
  if (-1 < this.className.indexOf(_class)) {
    this.classList.remove(_class);
  } else if (3 > document.getElementsByClassName(_class).length) {
    this.classList.add(_class);
  } else {
    console.warn('Oops !');
  }
  console.log('No. elements:', document.getElementsByClassName(_class).length, 'with class:', _class);
};
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  listItems[i].addEventListener('click', toggleClicked);
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>select up to 3 of your favourite items below.</p>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clickcnt = Math.max(clickcnt - 1, 0);` - this picks the maximum value of the two values.  If `clickcnt - 1` is below 0 it just returns 0 instead. See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min).

Your checking whether there is a class or not will fail though after adding one class and remove it, as it doesn't remove the attribute, just the class.  If you're using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) then you can use `this.classList.contains('clicked')`.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0z08um0r/).

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var clickcnt = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        if (this.classList.contains('clicked')) {
            this.classList.remove('clicked');
            clickcnt = Math.max(clickcnt - 1, 0);
        } else if (clickcnt < 3) {
            this.classList.add('clicked');
            clickcnt++;
        }
    });
}
```

To clean up a bit you can just use one `if` and the `toggle` method from the `classList` object.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0z08um0r/1/):

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
   listItems[i].addEventListener('click', clicked);
}

function clicked() {
    var clickCount = document.getElementsByClassName('clicked').length;
    var el = this;
    if (clickCount >= 3) {
        this.classList.remove('clicked');
    } else {
        this.classList.toggle('clicked');
    }
}
```

To have a global variable that's you can refer to for the click count in other functions you can change the code to:

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var clickCount = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
   listItems[i].addEventListener('click', clicked);
}

function clicked() {
    var el = this;
    if (clickCount >= 3) {
        this.classList.remove('clicked');
    } else {
        this.classList.toggle('clicked');
    }
   clickCount = document.getElementsByClassName('clicked').length;
}
```

Comment: the function looks great thanks however the click count seems to be out a bit compared to your first example. eg if you click the first item you get 0 but in your top eg you get 1?

Comment: @ak85 that's because I set the variable before I add the 'clicked' class (which then puts click count up 1 immediately after) but in this instance you need to know how many are *currently* clicked rather than how many are clicked after the click has happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - > http://jsfiddle.net/sumeetp1991/nybf6kk6/

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var clickcnt = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
     listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if(this.className){
        this.className = "";
        clickcnt--;
      }
      else if(clickcnt < 3) {
      this.className = "clicked";
      clickcnt++;
      }
    console.log(clickcnt);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like that?

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var clickcnt = 0;
var myList = document.querySelector('#mylist');

myList.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var itemClassList, selected, canAdd;
  
  itemClassList = event.target.classList;
  canAdd = clickcnt < 3;
  
  if (itemClassList.contains('clicked')) {
    itemClassList.remove('clicked');
    clickcnt -= 1;
  } else if (canAdd) {
    itemClassList.add('clicked');
    clickcnt += 1;
  }

});
```

```css
.clicked {
      background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<p>select up to 3 of your favourite items below.</p>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```